# What does "hasLayout = -1" in Buggy Old IE means...?

Tags: internet-explorer, haslayout

When hasLayout = -1 is it set to true or false....?

Thanks..!

Comment: In case , you are looking to avoid setting hasLayout property check http://www.positioniseverything.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customarily 0 indicates false and all other values are true.

However if it's an HTML attribute it might be parsed differently because Microsoft says [valid values are true or false](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533776(VS.85).aspx)

It appears that in your example, the intention of the programmer was to specify a true value (by customary means) but they should have used true or false, otherwise they might be conveying the wrong meaning.